# Join two tables, but not all keys are available in both

Tags: sql

I could not find a solution for this. Maybe also because it is a bit difficult to explain.

I got table1 with key1.
I got table2 with key2, value1.

My Statement:

```
Select * From table1 As t1
Left Join table2 As t2 On t2.key2 = t1.key1
Where t2.value1 Is Null Or t2.value1 > 123;
```

Now I have some key1 in table1, but not the corresponding key2 in table2. Because of that I do not have those keys in my result, but I need them in it. If the key in not in table2, then value1 sadly is not null. Is there some 'value' I can check there?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: you SQL requirement is not clear , can you explain it a bit - what exactly you want. Based on that you can use different join , which in your case seems completely possible , please share your requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, the condition on the `left join` would go in the `on` clause.

I suspect you want:

```
Select *
From table1 t1 Left Join
     table2 t2
     On t2.key2 = t1.key1 and t2.value1 > 123;
```

This will return all rows from `t1` along with matching rows -- if any -- from `table2`.

Your version will return all rows from `table1` where there is either a matching row with `value1 > 123` or no matching rows at all.  In other words, it will filter out rows from `table1` where all values in `table2` are `<= 123`.  This is only useful on very rare occasions.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below query and check

```
Select * From table1 As t1 INNER JOIN table2 As t2 On t2.key2 = t1.key1 Where t2.value1 Is NULL Or t2.value1 > 123;
```

It should work for your logic